# Nhibernate update problem - Parameter index is out of range

Tags: .net, nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I am having problem with updating data to database. I have a simple many-to-one Product - Group relationship:

```
    public class GroupInfoMapping : ClassMap<GroupInfo>
{
    public GroupInfoMapping()
    {
        Table("`group`");
        Schema("tempdb");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        Map(x => x.GroupName);
        Map(x => x.ParentId);
                       HasMany(x => x.Products)
                           .KeyColumn("GroupId")
                           .Inverse()
                           .Fetch.Select()
                           .AsSet();
                       //HasMany(x => x.Children)
                       //    .KeyColumn("Id")
                       //    .Inverse()
                       //    .Fetch.Select()
                       //    .Cascade.None()
                       //    .AsSet();
                       //References(x => x.Parent)
                       //    .Class(typeof(GroupInfo))
                       //    .Column("ParentId")
                       //    .Fetch.Select();

    }
}

     public class ProductInfoMapping : ClassMap<ProductInfo>
{
    public ProductInfoMapping()
    {
        Table("`product`");
        Schema("tempdb");
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();
        OptimisticLock.Version();
                       Map(x => x.GroupId);
        Map(x => x.ProductName);
                       References(x => x.Group)
                         .Class(typeof(GroupInfo))
                         .Column("GroupId")
                         .Fetch.Select();
    }
}
```

There is no difference if I change only the product data, it will not allow me to update with exception:
Parameter index is out of range.

If I add Not.Update() to Product Mapping for Group reference, I am able to update product data (but Group remains unreferenced).

I am using MySql database and I am using one session per presenter. Why I cannot update both entity and its reference? I have commented out part for selfreferening the group, since this also creates problem when updating group only.

Thanks,
Goran

Comment: What is the code that actually throws?

Comment: i often have this error when i use the same column twice in a mapping.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. This code was generated by  Visual Nhibernate, using the option "Include foreign key column" in One-to-many mapping. What is the proper way to have this property without the need to access the referencing entity itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ProductInfoMapping class, you are mapping the same column twice:

```
Map(x => x.GroupId);
```

and

```
References(x => x.Group)
    .Class(typeof(GroupInfo))
    .Column("GroupId")
    .Fetch.Select();
```

The *Map* of the group id is unneeded as you can access the id of the Group property without it:

```
var groupId = someProdInfoObj.Group.Id;
```

**Update:**

If you still desire that there be a *GroupId* property which you can access the id of the Group instead of accessing it directly on the Group object, you can just modify the property like so (example is for an id with a Guid type):

```
public virtual Guid? GroupId
{
    get { return Group != null ? Group.Id : null; }
    set { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. This code was generated by  Visual Nhibernate, using the option "Include foreign key column" in One-to-many mapping. What is the proper way to have this property without the need to access the referencing entity itself?

Comment: @Goran I've updated my answer to include a way you can have a GroupId property on your GroupInfo object.

Comment: I already tried this approach, but my problem is that I cannot sync between GroupId and Group. In your code you are actually making this property a read-only, so set is sufficient. I need GroupId to be read-write, so I can benefit from databinding synchronization.

If this is possible, I would like to know how. If it is not possible, then why VIsual NHibernate offers this as an option ( Include foreign key column")? I find it quite useful (EF also has it), especially in linq queries. Linq and databinding can work if I make it read-only like in your example, but I need updateble reference.

Comment: @Goran It appears Visual NHibernate used to always generate a property for the foreign key by default and making it optional was requested as can be shown [here](http://forums.slyce.com/index.php?showtopic=76).  Unfortunately, Visual NHibernate is just a mapping generator for NHibernate and mapping the same column twice (where the column has the potential to be written twice) is not allowed.  My guess is that NHibernate doesn't track changes to columns, rather changes to properties/fields and it wouldn't know if you changed GroupId it should change the reference Group to match.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will need to find a way around.